# Class number of certain polynomials

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f_n(x)=x^n-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}{x^i}$ and $A_n$ the number field corresponding to $f_n$.

> Question: Is the class number of $A_n$ always equal to one, or equivalently, is the ring of integers of $A_n$ a principal ideal domain?

This is true for $n \leq 16$ using MAGMA and also true for $n \leq 30$ assuming the GRH (according to MAGMA).

Comment: Just a side remark: These fields have been studied, e.g. Bary-Soroker, Shusterman and Zannier in the Appendix to https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05363 prove that their maximal totally real subfield is $\mathbb{Q}$. I am not aware of results regarding their class number though.