# For which $n$ is this ring an euclidean domain?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, computer-algebra, euclidean-domain

Let $f_n(x)=x^n-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}{x^i}$ and $A_n$ the number field corresponding to $f_n$.

> Question: Is $A_n$ for all $n$ an euclidean domain? Is there a good choice for an euclidean function?

Experiments suggest that $A_n$ might always be a principal ideal ring, see [Class number of certain polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363266/class-number-of-certain-polynomials) . Is there a way to check for being euclidean with a computer algebra system for small $n$ like $n<9$?

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain this might be true since "Assuming the extended Riemann hypothesis, if K is a finite extension of Q and the ring of integers of K is a PID with an infinite number of units, then the ring of integers is Euclidean."
By the sentence after that, $A_n$ is indeed euclidean for $n>8$ if it is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: There may be an algorithmic way of checking whether the ring is norm-Euclidean, but I highly doubt there is a way to check Euclidean-ness. For instance $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{14}]$ was only recently [proven to be Euclidean](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/is-euclidean/A20F443C0FDB4E3935DC1402C1060D74), by a method which very much is not just algorithmic.

Comment: What does "corresponding to $f_n$ mean when $f_n$ is not irreducible?